# How to delete a key in AWS S3 from javascript using http api

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I cannot seem to get past the `"403 (Forbidden)"` or the subsequent error `<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>` when I try to delete a key from my AWS S3. For testing I have made my bucket public, and have added CORS rules for DELETE, and allows s3:DeleteObject on all files in the directory like this: 
`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::...(directory)/*` .

Here is what I have tried in code so far:

```
function deleteS3file(bucket, path, filename) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if (Math.floor(xmlhttp.status/100) != 2){
             alert(filename +" not deleted from S3\n"+xmlhttp.status+" "+xmlhttp.responseText);
             // http://mysourceip.com/
         } else {
            console.log(filename +" deleted from S3");
         }
         }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("DELETE", bucket, true);
    xmlhttp.send(path+'/'+filename);
}
```

(this just gives me the 403 error)

and

```
function deleteS3file(bucket, path, filename) { // path without leading slash
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('key', path+filename); // full path to file
    fd.append('acl', 'bucket-owner-full-control');

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if (Math.floor(xmlhttp.status/100) != 2){
             alert(filename +" not deleted from S3\n"+xmlhttp.status+" "+xmlhttp.responseText);
             // http://mysourceip.com/
         } else {
            console.log(filename +" deleted from S3");
         }
         }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("DELETE", bucket, true);
    xmlhttp.send(fd);
}
```

(this gives me the 403 and the AWS Access Denied error)

I have an idea that my bucket config is correct because I can upload files with no issues. The AWS documentation seems to point to my first solution, yet then I don't even get an AWS response back.

Comment: 403 is always a permission error, check if IAM user/role has Deleteobject permission and the bucket doesn't have statement to deny deleteobject action, Is the bucket and IAM user/role in the same account ?

Comment: There are no deny's in the BucketPolicy, only allows. The user is just the browser executing the javascript code, right? i am testing with a public bucket. So the user/role is "unknown" to the bucket, right?

Comment: There is always an implicit deny in the bucket policy if no allow statement is present , you need to check 1) Public Access setting for both bucket and account level 2) I wouldn't suggest it but for public , a bucket statement with allow for principle * (everyone) for putobject or a bucket access control policy for everyone write access.  (use presigned url instead for security)